# csv filter on linux bash

Tags: linux, awk, csv

**Problem:**

I have a CSV file with 5 columns (1st column is a string and the other 4 are int). I would like to filter based on the third column, Revenues, the largest on the top and smallest on the bottom in a new CSV file.

It seems that I would need to use something like `awk -F '","'  'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (Revenues($5) > ?? print }' Valuation.csv > Ranking.csv`

**Data:**

```
Company,Nbr employees, Revenues  , Revenues per employee , Valuation 
Facebook,"35,587","55,800,000,000","1,567,988","491,000,000,000"
Uber,"16,000","11,300,000,000","706,250","120,000,000,000"
Snapchat,"3,069","1,180,000,000","384,490","7,200,000,000"
Airbnb,"3,100","2,600,000,000","838,710","38,000,000,000"
LinkedIn,"13,000","26,200,000,000","2,015,385","26,200,000,000"
Coursora,280,"140,000,000","500,000","815,000,000"
Google,"98,771","39,120,000,000","396,068","720,000,000,000"
Stripe,"1,500","450,000,000","300,000","22,500,000,000"
Epic Games,700,"3,000,000,000","4,285,714","15,000,000,000"
Grab,"3,000","2,750,000,000","916,667","10,000,000,000"
Pinterest,800,"1,000,000,000","1,250,000","12,000,000,000"
```

Comment: Your file does not appear to be a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 head -1 Valuation.csv > Ranking.csv && tail -n+2 Valuation.csv | sort -t '"' -nrk4 >> Ranking.csv
```

- `head ....` will copy the header to Ranking file
- `tail .... | sort ...` will sort the 4th column by excluding the header with `"` as a delimiter.
- `-n+2` will print the file from 2nd line
- `-nrk4` numeric reverse sort of the fourth column with `"` as a delimiter.

**Output :**

```
Company,Nbr employees, Revenues  , Revenues per employee , Valuation 
Facebook,"35,587","55,800,000,000","1,567,988","491,000,000,000"
Google,"98,771","39,120,000,000","396,068","720,000,000,000"
LinkedIn,"13,000","26,200,000,000","2,015,385","26,200,000,000"
Uber,"16,000","11,300,000,000","706,250","120,000,000,000"
Grab,"3,000","2,750,000,000","916,667","10,000,000,000"
Airbnb,"3,100","2,600,000,000","838,710","38,000,000,000"
Snapchat,"3,069","1,180,000,000","384,490","7,200,000,000"
Stripe,"1,500","450,000,000","300,000","22,500,000,000"
Epic Games,700,"3,000,000,000","4,285,714","15,000,000,000"
Pinterest,800,"1,000,000,000","1,250,000","12,000,000,000"
Coursora,280,"140,000,000","500,000","815,000,000"
```